# How can I acces code from an array inside attay with diffrent names

Tags: php, arrays, loops

How can I acces all the `code's` in the arrays inside the data array. because they all have diffrent name's and I don't have control over that.

*index.php*

```
<?php
$getVoucherList = "https://www.planyo.com/rest/?method=list_vouchers&api_key=yourkey&resource_id=110556";
$cleanVoucherList = preg_replace("/ /", "%20", $getVoucherList);
$voucherlist = file_get_contents("$cleanVoucherList");
$voucherList = json_decode($voucherlist, true);

var_dump($voucherList['data']);
var_dump($voucherList['data']['results']['testvoucher']['code']);
foreach ($voucherList as $value){
  echo "$value";
}
?>
```

*how my `var_dump();`looks*
https://imagebin.ca/v/3xEh0H8inuj3

Comment: With a `foreach`, you know what is it, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop through `$voucherList['data']['results']` array to access individual test voucher codes,

```
// your code
foreach($voucherList['data']['results'] as $testVoucher => $testVoucherArr){
    echo $testVoucherArr['code'] . '<br />';
}
```